# The package python3.2 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: installation, python, software-sources, python3

I get this error when I try to update or run software center, but I can't find an archive for it:

```
The package python3.2 needs to be reinstalled
```

Comment: In the Ubuntu Software Center the package python3.2 is called python3. Maybe this is an Ubuntu version thing, but anyway you can check the name of the package by searching for python3 in the Ubuntu Software Center to check if python3 is indeed the package name of your package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Synaptic Package Manager' to reinstall python3.2

Download synaptic with terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed, open synaptic (you need to type in your password) and mark the following dependencies (see screenshot) for installation, then hit the <kbd>apply</kbd> button:

[image]

---

Another option is to simply download it directly, using terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.2
```

[image]

Like in the screenshot you are prompted for `Y/N` option. Hit `Y` then <kbd>enter</kbd> button.